# Getting Timeout for the request made from Static Library( NSURLErrorDomain error -1001)

Tags: ios, timeout, static-libraries

Getting Timeout for the request made from Static Library( NSURLErrorDomain error -1001) for iOS device.Request parameters are proper. Not able to identify what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1001 error code stands for time out, this happens if the server we are requesting to is not reachable.

Things you can perform ..

1. Check your internet connection.
2. Check if the server you are trying to approach is on and working.
3. Try pinging " ping 'your server address' "